# Clicking noise from TT 1.8l turbo engine

Tags: engine, audi, clicking, tt

My Audi TT 8N (224 Quattro) has started making a clicking noise that seems to be coming from the engine.

The noise appeared suddenly while accelerating. The engine doesn't seem to be low on power.

Any ideas what this could be? Is my engine toasted?

Here is a video showcasing the sound :
https://youtu.be/0ktrZ5gBrCE

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the year of the vehicle. The Audi 1.8l turbo 1998-2008 has had a number of engine failures due to oil sludging and the heat generated by the turbo which is very hard on engine oil. A couple things to consider:

- Check the oil level
- Is the engine oil dirty
- Has the oil been serviced per the manufactures recommendation
- Have the oil pressure checked to ensure it is within spec
- It could be the valve lifters are worn and need adjusting
- Fuel injectors are failing
- Cam tensioner is failing. This could be due to the aforementioned oil sludging

I would recommend taking your vehicle to a reliable independent mechanic and have the above checked out to determine the cause and the condition of your engine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it would be important - it's a 2002 model.